# $D_1(0)=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|< 1\}$ is not compact

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, proof-verification

This is the proof I wrote for $D_1(0)=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|< 1\}$ is not compact.

$$
\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}D_{1-(1/n)}(0)
$$ is clearly a open covering of $D_1(0)$.

Consider the finite sub-collection $\bigcup_{n=2}^{k}D_{1-(1/n)}(0)$ of $\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}D_{1-(1/n)}(0)$.

Assume that $D_1(0) ⊆ \bigcup_{n=2}^{k}D_{1-(1/n)}(0)$. 
Choose $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1-(1/2k)$.

Then $z\in D_1(0)$ but $|z|=1-(1/2k)>1-(1/k)$. Hence $z∉\bigcup_{n=2}^{k}D_{1-(1/n)}(0)$. This is a contradiction hence $D_1(0)$ is not compact.

I am not sure whether this proof is correct. Hope someone could help to improve this. THanks

Comment: Essentially your proof is correct.

Comment: @drhab Corrected it. But my problem is whether it is more appropriate to take the finite sub collection as $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}D_{1-(1/n_i)}(0)$ instead of what I have taken. Maybe sort of generalizes it more. I am not sure though

Comment: Any finite subcollection as mentioned in your comment is contained in a collection of the sort mentioned in your answer. So what you suggest in your comment will not be an improvement. On the contrary: the proof will loose some of its elegance :).

Comment: Note also that $\bigcup_{n=2}^k D_{1-(1/n)}(0)=D_{1-(1/k)}(0)$.

Comment: @drhab So the proof is good as it is? Thanks !

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for the observation but it does affect the answer right?

Comment: @Heisenberg No, it doesn't affect anything; your proof is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Alternatively, the continuous function $z\mapsto (1-z)^{-1}$ on this set is not uniformly continuous, alternatively it doesn't achieve a maximum.

Comment: Not familiar with Hausdorff spaces. I hope you don;t mean my proof is wrong

Comment: @Heisenberg Your proof is fine. I am suggesting ways to prove the claim different from finding an open cover without a finite subcover.